# Django csrf token

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

views.py

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
context.update(csrf(request))
{'csrf_token': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xae0f4ec>}
```

I am trying to add csrf token to my forms.i m generating csrf token in the views like above.But csrf_token value gives some **proxy** object like the one shown above instead of string.I m using django 1.3.Thanks in advance for any sort of help.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? Aren't you using `RequestContext` and `{%csrf_token%}` in template.

Comment: @Rohan i m not using RequestContext but i m using {%csrf_token%} in template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The csrf method is lazy, it returns a Promise/Proxy. Once this object is called in the template, the template engine will unicode this object which triggers the real method.

Try this:

```
print unicode(csrf(request)['csrf_token'])
```

Comment: @Willain yes now i get the string.but in template i don't have hidden field eventhough i m using {%csrf_token%} template tag.

Comment: is CsrfViewMiddleware in your middleware? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Comment: @Willain yes i do have django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware

Comment: What django version are you using?